# Why does it take over a minute for the desktop to load after logging in?

Tags: kernel

After entering the login-password, it takes more than a minute before the desktop is shown.

`The output of dmesg`:

```
[ 2030.004228] audit_printk_skb: 156 callbacks suppressed
[ 2030.004231] type=1400 audit(1389169706.701:71): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" parent=3598 profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-pdf" pid=3602 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 2030.004240] type=1400 audit(1389169706.701:72): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" parent=3598 profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=3602 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 2030.004904] type=1400 audit(1389169706.701:73): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" parent=3598 profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=3602 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 3090.435641] perf samples too long (2510 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 50000
[11285.003065] perf samples too long (5009 > 5000), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 25000
```

`And the output of uname -a`:

```
Linux Bedc-Linux-ThinkPad-R500 3.11.0-15-generic #23-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 9 18:16:27 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

What is going on here?

Comment: The "perf samples too long" thing is https://lkml.org/lkml/2013/5/29/640 ... not sure what you're asking beyond that, though.

Comment: The fact is that, after entering the log-in password, it takes more than a minute before the desktop is shown.

Answer (score 1):

You're running 32-bit Ubuntu on a machine that can't be faster than a Core2Duo, and which might even be just a CoreDuo.  If you're running the main version, loading Unity and all the eyecandy that comes with it will likely take a while.  My own Core2Duo laptop chokes on it too.

Solution would be to use a lighter window manager.  Personally I switched my laptop to Linux Mint Debian and use the MATE desktop on it.

If it's a Core2Duo, switch to 64-bit, that will help a lot.

Applying the Intel microcode patches and compiling your own kernel to be optimized for the processor make a fairly significant difference too, and aren't all that difficult.

If you're really going for performance, consider looking into Gentoo or Arch.  It's more work to maintain, but you'd be amazed how much difference optimizing the builds for your particular hardware can make for some kinds of tasks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late here but I just solved a similar problem:

- system freezes, especially right after login
- also on a Thinkpad (T400)
- same dmesg messages about 'samples too long'

with the help of the Arch wiki:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Intel_graphics#X_freeze.2Fcrash_with_intel_driver

After disabling hardware acceleration the problem is gone.

Comment: Better late than never.